# Why does pylint3 not like python-ldap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-ldap

I'm trying to lint my Python code that uses the [python-ldap](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap) module however pylint3 always gives the errors below:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module python.test
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
E:  2, 0: No name 'filter' in module 'ldap' (no-name-in-module)
E:  2, 0: Unable to import 'ldap.filter' (import-error)
E:  5,26: Module 'ldap' has no 'filter' member (no-member)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at -30.00/10 (previous run: -30.00/10, +0.00)
```

Here is my test.py file that I ran this on:

```py
import ldap
import ldap.filter

print('ldap:', dir(ldap))
print('ldap.filter:', dir(ldap.filter))
```

I cannot figure out why it doesn't like this. I have tried using a default pylintrc file with `extension-pkg-whitelist=_ldap` which I saw other projects do that use python-ldap however that did not change anything. If I run this code with python3 it runs with no errors, so I really don't understand why's going on.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 18.04 if that matters. I installed python-ldap with pip3.

Comment: @BaileyKocin Uhh, yea. I'm trying to use it to analyze my other python code. However, when I use python-ldap it gives a ton of errors like seen above... I'm trying to figure that out. Can you help with that?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, my pylint score was 7.5/10 because I was missing a module docstring.

Comment: @d_kennetz Thanks for pointing that out. I just installed on a different system and see the same as you now on the second system (working, with 7.5 score). There must be a problem with the installation on the first machine.

Comment: On my build system it is working properly, but still can't figure out what is wrong with my one dev system. So I think i'm just gonna give up on trying to diagnose it for now since our build system is reporting properly.

Comment: if anyone stumbles on this, I have some older systems on python 3.6 and I experience this same issue on those systems.  Same code base on newer python 3.7+ do not experience the issue.